# How to remove anchor from url after checking radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to remove an anchor from url or "untarget" the element when i click on radio button.

Here's the code, when i click on a link from the first page i want to have control on specific element on the second page (for example changing font color) but the problem I am struggling with is i can't "untarget" it by using css after i choose sth else from the radio button list and there are simultaneously highlighted two links at the same time.

First page:

```html
<a href="oferta.html">OFERTA</a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="oferta.html#webdesign">webdesign</a></li>
  <li><a href="oferta.html#grafika">grafika</a></li>
  <li><a href="oferta.html#kampania">kampania</a></li>
</ul>
```

Second page:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  *{
    clear: both;
  }
  label:target{
    color: red;
  }
  #webdesign:target ~ #wd, #grafika:target ~ #gr, #kampania:target ~ #kp{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked + #webdesign, input[type=radio]:checked + #grafika, input[type=radio]:checked + #kampania{
    color: red;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked + #webdesign ~ #wd, input[type=radio]:checked + #grafika ~ #gr, input[type=radio]:checked + #kampania ~ #kp{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #wd, #gr, #kp{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  #wd{
    background: red;
  }
  #gr{
    background: green;
  }
  #kp{
    background: blue;
  }
</style>

<a href="home.html">HOME</a>


<input type="radio" id="webdesign1" name="labels">
<label for="webdesign1" id="webdesign">webdesign</label>

<input type="radio" id="grafika1" name="labels">
<label for="grafika1" id="grafika">grafika</label>

<input type="radio" id="kampania1" name="labels">
<label for="kampania1" id="kampania">kampania</label>


<div id="wd"></div>
<div id="gr"></div>
<div id="kp"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It seems that it works fine: http://output.jsbin.com/wesotoh#webdesign

Comment: But notice that when you click on different radio button that it's currently targeted (#webdesign) two labels has red color. I need only one to be colored thats why i need to remove target attribute after i click on another radio button

Comment: "two labels has red color." - I cannot see 2 labels getting red. I click one radio only that respective label is red.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa read his comment: `when you click on different radio button that it's currently targeted (#webdesign) two labels has red color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Attach the first `change` event of any radio, than remove the `hash` part from the URL.

Assuming you are using jQuery:

```js
$('input:radio').one('change', function(){
  location.hash = '';
});
```

http://jsbin.com/wesotoh/edit?html,js